# Why lots of things works 2^n in processors archectures?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, microprocessors

I am an freshgraduated engineer, so that ı want to learn some basics in these area.
I want to learn why everything is referred with 2 and its overs in microprocessors?
Why our storages are **256kb, 1024kb**? Why our microprocessors are **4-8-16-32 bits?**

Comment: What did your research on exponentiation to the base of 2 reveal? What did your research on "digital" and its underlying number base reveal? (Please remember to add clarification by [edit]ing your question.)

Comment: what kind of engineer?  you didnt cover binary nor transistors nor anything?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor#Simplified_operation, transistor as a switch.

Comment: we have 10 fingers, 10 dollar bills, 100 dollar bills and other things related to 10. we dont have 17 dollar bills and 64 dollar bills, because.........more than enough hints to answer the question, you basically know the answer because it is in the title question.

Comment: processors started off being 9 and 18 and powers of 3 before they were powers of four, that might take you a little more work to figure out, but is equally simple.  a few seconds with any of the classic dec processor documents and there you go...